How can I extract shapes out of a photo?
I want to get some shapes out of my pictures. They often aren't as uniform to select them with the magic wand tool (no matter the tolerance).
Is there an easy way to extract them?
Select > Color Range doesn't work either. I always get some small points missing.
Also is there a way, besides feathering the edges to get some clean but not sharp result?
(I want to use them in a collage, but they shouldn't look like the just pasted on top.)


Have you tried using the Quick Select tool?  see a turorial

No matter how you end up making the selection, I recommend making a mask instead of just copy/pasting the selection destructively. That way it's much easier to refine the mask later to make it blend better with the background.
